FeatureClassToFeatureClass Error 010273
I am trying to run the code below to import a feature service and then convert it to a feature class that is stored on my local database. The code is failing at the DelParcels section, but when I run this section on its own it works fine. Im not sure whats going on. Why does this script seem to only work sometimes. See code and error message below.
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
#Clean map of all old layers from any older script runs
project = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
Stage = project.listMaps("Stage")[0]

for i in Stage.listLayers():
    Stage.removeLayer(i)
    
for tbl in Stage.listTables():
    Stage.removeTable(tbl)
    
#==========================================================================================
FrankParcels = arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass(r'https://gis.franklincountyohio.gov/hosting/rest/services/ParcelFeatures/Parcel_Features/MapServer/0',
                                           r"G:\Shared drives\WISGIS\Scripts\Bata_Scripts\Default.gdb",'FrankParcels')

DelParcels = arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass(r'https://maps.delco-gis.org/arcgiswebadaptor/rest/services/DelawareCountyData/MapServer/0',
                                           r"G:\Shared drives\WISGIS\Scripts\Bata_Scripts\Default.gdb",'DelParcels')

boundary = Stage.addDataFromPath(r'https://services.arcgis.com/OrM4sGBhxpl5PoQe/arcgis/rest/services/City_Boundary/FeatureServer/24')
#==========================================================================================

#Select the features that are 2 mile buffer around the Westerville_boundary layer
arcpy.management.SelectLayerByLocation(FrankParcels,'WITHIN_A_DISTANCE',Westerville_boundary, '7 Miles')```

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ExecuteError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [1]:
Line 16:    DelParcels = arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass(r'https://maps.delco-gis.org/arcgiswebadaptor/rest/services/DelawareCountyData/MapServer/0',

File C:\Users\chace.carpenter_west\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\conversion.py, in FeatureClassToFeatureClass:
Line 2936:  raise e

File C:\Users\chace.carpenter_west\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\conversion.py, in FeatureClassToFeatureClass:
Line 2933:  retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(*gp_fixargs((in_features, out_path, out_name, where_clause, field_mapping, config_keyword), True)))

File C:\Users\chace.carpenter_west\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py, in <lambda>:
Line 512:   return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))

ExecuteError: ERROR 010273: Error in reading table.
Failed to execute (FeatureClassToFeatureClass).


From Feature Class To Feature Class (Conversion) - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation, "This is a deprecated tool. This functionality has been replaced by the Export Features tool."

I tested the same service and get the same error.  You will need to contact the organization because it is an issue with the service and not the tool.

I was able to get this to work by putting the featclasstofeatureclass function in a try block and rerunning the function when an error is raised. I this common feature services/ rest api?
    try:
        FrankParcels = arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass(r'https://gis.franklincountyohio.gov/hosting/rest/services/ParcelFeatures/Parcel_Features/MapServer/0',
                                                                   r"G:\Shared drives\WISGIS\Scripts\Bata_Scripts\Default.gdb",'FrankParcels')
        break
    except:
        print(f'Attempt {i+1} Delaware feature class download failed. Retrying....')

time.sleep(5)
for i in range(3):
    try:
        DelParcels = arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass(r'https://maps.delco-gis.org/arcgiswebadaptor/rest/services/DelawareCountyData/MapServer/0',
                                                                 r"G:\Shared drives\WISGIS\Scripts\Bata_Scripts\Default.gdb",'DelParcels')
        break
    except:
        print(f'Attempt {i+1} Delaware feature class download failed. Retrying....')```

